# Use of Unregistered tlb files in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, winsxs

I want to use unregistered tlb files. I figured out that can be done using WinSxS.

Now my question is how do I create manifest file from the tlb file. Mt.exe utility requires dll option to be specified when tlb option is used.

Can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Use the `#import` directive as described in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: #import directive is already being used. I have unregistered both dll and tlb files. I dynamically load the dll file from WinSxS. I am looking for a way to install .tlb file in WinSxS and load the tlb file dynamically with my dll file. How do I create manifest file for the tlb file